# Vue3 global style make the child component style not to work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, less, vite

The global style has been added to the scope, making the child component is not working.

```
.border[data-v-d0e06bca] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.all-center[data-v-d0e06bca] {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

vite.config.ts

```
css:{
      preprocessorOptions:{
        less: {
          javascriptEnabled: true,
          additionalData: '@import "./src/styles/global.less";',
        },
      }
    },
```

I have done anything that I can